# Problem with Samba 4.3.8

Tags: active-directory, samba4

I've installed samba (`v.4.3.8`) in Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 and provision a domain but when I try to join a Windows Client to domain, a `Network resource is not available` error is shown.

[image: Error picture].

Although if I repeat the same process but using samba `v.4.1.6`, all the process works fine and I can join the windows client.
Is there any news about this problem with Samba?

Comment: What's your actual question? “Is there any news” is not really a question that falls within the scope of this community.

Answer (score 0):

How were you able to install an old version of samba? I am having a similar issue but need to revert to an old version since this new version also broke my shares.

Found an answer:

> apt-get install samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
>   samba-common=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-libs=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
>   samba-common-bin=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
>   samba-dsdb-modules=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
>   python-samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 libldb1=1:1.1.16-1
>   python-ldb=1:1.1.16-1

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when upgrading from Samba 4.1.6 to Samba 4.3.8 on multiple servers (apt-get upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
Samba users could not connect anymore, and in some conditions Samba was even dumping core.

1. I made a backup of /etc/samba/smb.conf
2. I performed these steps:

   > service smbd stop
   >   apt-get remove samba-common --purge
   >   rm -Rf /etc/samba
   >   apt-get autoremove
   >   apt-get purge samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
   >   apt-get update
   >   apt-get install samba
3. Restored /etc/samba/smb.conf
4. Restarted smbd

Samba users can connect again, yay!

Comment: it looks like going your way my problem with samba is solved. At the moment I get no more error message in connection with samba.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug on 4.3.8. To solve it, just install winbind and libnss-winbind packages. No additional configuration needed.